# Mount error(22): Invalid argument

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, debugging

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm having some problems mounting a NAS with CIFS

I've been searching the forums for 3 days now to find a solution that could help me.

Here is what I tested :

The command I am trying to execute is:

> `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.253/General /home/nekop/Bureau/NAS-General -o credentials=/home/nekop/Documents/.creds,vers=1.0`

And in the future, enter it in the /etc/fstab file with this line :

> `//192.168.1.253/General /home/nekop/Bureau/NAS-General  cifs    credentials=/home/nekop/Documents/.creds,vers=1.0       0       0`

After their executions, both return the error "**mount error(22): Invalid argument**"
In the details of "**sudo demsg**" : "**VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22**"

I use a very old NAS which uses the SMB1.5 protocol at most and not above
I updated Ubuntu, the packages I downloaded (cifs-utils) and still nothing
The "**sec=ntlm**" option does not work either and gives me the error : "**VFS: bad security option: ntlm**"

I was also able to test with another machine on Ubuntu Server with a public IP and it worked.

I ping my NAS address correctly

I'm calling for help because I'm tearing my hair out over this problem.
If you need more information on versions ect... Do not hesitate to ask me !
I thank you in advance for your attention to this request.

Comment: Check the spelling ... '-o redentials='  should be '-o credentials='

Comment: Sorry, I re-erited incorrectly, I typed the command correctly and stile not work

Comment: Read `man mount mount.cifs`. Error 22 is "Invalid argument". It's telling you that `ntlm` is not a valid choice to follow `sec=`.

Comment: Yes but i dont specify the sec= and ntlmi doesn't work and other is above SMB1

Comment: I wonder if your cifs kernel module is configured with `disable_legacy_dialects` set to `y`? You can check by installing the `sysfsutils` package and then executing `systool -vm cifs`. You may also want to check the kernel config file ex. `grep CONFIG_CIFS /boot/config-$(uname -r)` in particular the value of `CONFIG_CIFS_ALLOW_INSECURE_LEGACY`

Comment: ... although while that replicates the `mount error(22): Invalid argument` error, dmesg on my kernel reports `CIFS: VFS: mount with legacy dialect disabled` when I do that

Comment: After installing `sysfsutils` the command `systool -vm cifs` return "**Error opening module cifs**"

Comment: And for `grep CONFIG_CIFS /boot/config-$(uname -r)`the value of `CONFIG_CIFS_ALLOW_INSECURE_LEGACY` is set to **y**

Comment: Hmm... so are you able to manually load the module (`sudo modprobe cifs` or `sudo modprobe -v cifs` for verbose output)?

Comment: Yes now i can do `sudo systool -vm cifs | grep disable` and is set to "**N**".
Two questions : How can i change this to "**y**" ?
And i have to modprobe cifs every time i turn on the PC ?

Comment: `disable_legacy_dialects= "N"` is what you want in this context (it's the opposite logic to that of the `CONFIG_CIFS_ALLOW_INSECURE_LEGACY` parameter). Now that you have manually loaded the cifs module, does your `sudo mount -t cifs ...` command still error out?

Comment: Ah ok my bad. And the command mount still return error :/

Comment: OK sorry I'm out of ideas

Comment: Please run the following command to see exactly what the server is capable of and post the results: `nmap --script smb-protocols ip-address-of-nas`

Comment: Here the result :
`Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.253
Host is up (0.0064s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp   open  ipp
667/tcp   open  disclose
50000/tcp open  ibm-db2

Host script results:
| smb-protocols: 
|   dialects: 
|_    NT LM 0.12 (SMBv1) [dangerous, but default] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server truly requires sec=ntlm I see no other way around this but to use the samba client and not mount.cifs. And even there you you likely need to roll back the newer security settings.

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the **workgroup = WORKGROUP** line add these:

```
client min protocol = NT1
client NTLMv2 auth = No
client lanman auth = Yes
```

Then do a gio mount:

```
gio mount smb://192.168.1.253/General
```

It will mount - if successful - under /run/user/$UID/gvfs

*Note: mount.cifs and the samba client are two different things. CIFS is controlled by the Linux kernel itself and doesn't reference smb.conf.*

Comment: My goal is to mount the share into "/home/nekop/Bureau/NAS-General" permanently
How can i do this with smb:// ?

Comment: You can use gigolo to do the actual automounting then create a symlink from the /run/user/$UID/gvfs/'smb-share:server=192.168.1.253,share=General' mountpoint to /home/nekop/Bureau folder.

Comment: Its good ! Thx for your help